# "Для начала" и "прежде чем" могут соседствовать в предложении?

Tags: тавтология

> Я была заворожена прыжками в воду, но, прежде чем исполнять
>   акробатические элементы в воздухе, нужно было для начала серьёзно
>   проработать их в зале.

*Перво-наперво* вместо *для начала* не изменит стилистику? А смутительную ситуацию - поправит? О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

*Я была заворожена прыжками в воду, но, прежде чем исполнять все эти акробатические элементы,   нужно было  **как минимум** серьёзно проработать их в зале.*

*Я была заворожена прыжками в воду, но, прежде чем исполнять все эти акробатические элементы,   **первым делом** нужно было  серьёзно проработать их в зале.*

Пояснение

Немного странно в одном предложении выглядят  обстоятельства ***в воду, в воздухе, в зале*.** Вроде бы  и так понятно, что речь идет о воздушной акробатике.

Comment: Речь о спорткомлексе "Олимпийский".

Answer (score 1):

При таком построении предложения употребление того и другого сразу едва ли оправдано. "Прежде чем..." может уточнять менее конкретное "для начала" (почему начинать надо было с того-то):

> Для начала нужно было серьёзно проработать акробатические элементы в
>   зале - прежде чем исполнять их в воздухе.

Здесь (как и в исходном предложении) "для начала" (= сначала) относится к тому, что следовало сделать в первую очередь, но возможно употребление этого словосочетания в качестве вводной конструкции со смыслом "для начала (нужно сказать следующее)", - и в таком случае "прежде чем" с ней не конфликтует.

Answer (score 0):

Я была заворожена прыжками в воду, но оказалось, чтобы мечта прыгать исполнилась, мне надо было для начала — прежде, чем исполнять их в воздухе, — серьёзно проработать акробатические элементы в зале.